# How to ignore responding to stored '&lt' and '&gt' text in Oracle SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have an issue when writing the sql query below in SQL Command line. It asks me *"Enter a value for lt:"* and then gives error

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I need to properly read the column that includes '&lt' or '&gt' as a string. How can I edit the query to make it works?

```
Delete from authorization1 
where role = 'staff' AND object = ' /department/gradstudent/gpa' 
AND predicate = ' & l t ; 2.0') AND action = 'read'
```

Comment: extra `)` in the statement. remove that

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `SQL*Plus` or `SQL Developer` as your front end, this issue is that `&foo` is the syntax for defining substitution variables.  You can

```
set define off;
```

before running your script to disable substitution variables.  That will stop the front end from prompting you for a value.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using Oracle 11g command line and 'set define off' worked and prevented the entering message, but the record is not deleted. However, it is deleted when I write "Delete from authorization1 where predicate = ' & l t ; 2.0'". something wrong with the original delete query.

Comment: @AliAlwohaibi - You'd have to investigate what is wrong with the `delete` statement.  Logically, one of the other three predicates must be incorrect.  The leading space on the `object = ' /department...'` predicate looks suspicious to me but I don't know your data.  The spaces between &, l, t, and ; also look suspicious.

Comment: @AliAlwohaibi - how many record are returned if you query for those records by doing:  `SELECT * FROM authorization1 
where role = 'staff' AND object = ' /department/gradstudent/gpa' 
AND predicate = ' & l t ; 2.0') AND action = 'read'`?

Comment: @AliAlwohaibi  - is there supposed to be a leading space in `' /department/gradstudent/gpa'`? It just looks a bit odd...